# how to restrict access to certain parts of a view laravel

Tags: php, laravel, access-control

i want to restrict certain parts of a view if a user is not a guest/admin is not supposed to see.the application has 3 users admin,vendor,customer

```
 @if (Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->role == 'customer') 
     <div class="collapse show" id="users-nav">
         <ul class="nav nav-sm flex-column">
             <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('profile.edit') }}">
                     {{ __('User Profile') }}
                 </a>
             </li>
```

am getting the error

The vendor doesnt see too that part and i want him to see together with admin

Comment: Please can you show where you declared the `customer()` function?

Comment: for simple auth check in Blade, you can use `@auth`/`@endauth` or `@guest`/`@endguest` to wrap sections of your code that shouldn't be displayed.

Comment: i've updated my code @dparoli

Answer (score 3):

You should change your `if clause` from this:

```php
@if (Auth::check() && !Auth::user()->role == 'customer')
```

To this:

```php
@if (Auth::check() && !(Auth::user()->role == 'customer'))
```

Or to this (as pointed by @miken32), easier to read:

```php
@if (Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->role !== 'customer'))
```

The first one is always false, pay attention to round brackets.

Comment: I'd say `Auth::user()->role !== 'customer'` would be more unambiguous.

Comment: @miken32 you're probably right my brain got twisted with `&& !`, I only know that the clause posted by the OP is always false :)

Comment: @Allgeekish please consider accepting the answer if it solves the problem you posted

Answer (score 2):

Blade provides several shortcuts for checking if a user is signed in. for example:

```
@auth
    <p>Only logged in users can view this</p>
    <a href="/logout">Logout</a>
@endauth

@guest
    <p>Only non-logged in users can view this</p>
    <a href="/login">Login</a>
@endguest
```

You can view additional blade templating if statements here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#if-statements

Comment: the thing is i have 3 levels of users customer,admin,vendor i want the user not to view that part of the view blade.only the vendor and admin

Comment: Sorry, I understand now. It seems that the solution from dparoli would achieve what you are looking to do.